# crypto.load_certificate() throws 'no start line'

Tags: pyopenssl

I am trying to open an encoded X509 certificate using the
following command

---

## !/usr/bin/python

from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL

### crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, 'ca_file.pem')

But after execution I get the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cert_from_sign_req.py", line 13, in 
    "ca_file.pem")
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1511, in load_certificate
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 48, in exception_from_error_queue
OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('PEM routines', 'PEM_read_bio', 'no start line')]

Can someone help me to understand what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already found the reason. My sample code was written using article in docs.genati.org
http://docs.ganeti.org/ganeti/2.14/html/design-x509-ca.html
but apparently there was a mistake. Problem was that the last argument should be buffer of file and not the path location.
It should be 
crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, file('ca_file.pem').read())